# Authentication failure logging into website

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies, python-requests

I am trying to log into this website: https://portals.broadinstitute.org/cmap/index.jsp using code from some time back from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22547541/651779. This used to work correctly. However, when running it now I get an authorization denied. The username and password are correct.

Below the code:

```
login_url = 'http://www.broadinstitute.org/cmap/j_security_check'

login_values = urllib.parse.urlencode({'j_username': user,
                                       'j_password': pwd, 
                                       'submit': 'sign in'})
print(login_url+'?'+login_values)
```

This gives the url (with username and password filled in):

```
http://www.broadinstitute.org/cmap/j_security_check?j_username=<username>&j_password=<password>&submit=sign+in
```

When I paste that in my browser it correctly logs me in, so I know the username and password are still good.

```
payload_submit_signature = bytes(login_values, 'ascii')

cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(
    urllib.request.HTTPRedirectHandler(),
    urllib.request.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0),
    urllib.request.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=0),
    urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

opener.open(submit_signature_url) #First call to capture the JSESSIONID
resp = opener.open(login_url, payload_submit_signature)
for cookie in cj:
    print (cookie.name, cookie.value, cookie.domain, cookie.expires, cookie.secure) #etc etc
```

As per the previous stack answer a cookie needs to be set first. The print above gives

```
JSESSIONID B2CFD19CBB9105EC2DC4D75DD7C3C0C9 portals.broadinstitute.org None True
```

so that seems to work.

```
print(resp.read())
```

This gives the same hmtl page you get when filling in the wrong user-password combination. How come it's not sending these correctly?

Comment: Why don't you use `requests` ?

Comment: @t.m.adam 

`payload = {'j_username': user,  'j_password': pwd}
with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('http://www.broadinstitute.org/cmap/j_security_check', data=payload)
    print (p.text)
`
also gives authentication error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `requests` , this code works for me

```
login = 'https://portals.broadinstitute.org/cmap/j_security_check'
index = 'https://portals.broadinstitute.org/cmap/index.jsp'
username = 'my username'
password = 'my password'
data = { 'j_username':username, 'j_password':password, 'submit':'sign+in' }

ses = requests.Session()
ses.get(index)    # you need this to get cookies #
post = ses.post(login, data=data)

print(ses.cookies.get_dict())
print(post.url)
print('sign out' in post.content)
```

Result :

```
{'JSESSIONID': 'A86EDB10DB2BC063EFE7A528F5E88A77'}
https://portals.broadinstitute.org/cmap/index.jsp
True
```