# Is there a new/updated Twill?

Tags: python, printing, scripting, syntax-error, twill

I've been trying to learn Twill Scripting on Python and I am using **Python 3.4 and Twill 1.8.0**. Been reading some posts here and I found it interesting to study. But, I do have a problem installing Twill. I just knew that **PRINT** in Python is now a function so meaning it needs parenthesis and that's where my problem starts. As I look through the codes on Twill 1.8.0, I think it isn't oriented with the change of using PRINT yet. Strings are not enclosed with parenthesis so I was thinking maybe there is a new patch or version of Twill that adapts the changes of Python, is there any? or is there anything I can do about this aside from manually editing Twill files?

Your response is highly appreciated.

Comment: I think it's a legitimate question whether Twill is available for Python3. Upvoted to cancel out the malicious downvote.

Answer (score 3):

I just found the answer. Thanks for viewing this question and probably for that downvote (SAD FACE).. So, the solution that I found was to use the 2to3 Script Tool found in Python Folder. Basically, it refactors Python 2 codes to Python 3 codes.

Comment: I tried that too and could successfully install Twill 1.8.0. But when I try to `from twill.commands import *`, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'`. I use Python 3.6. How did you deal with that?

Comment: Actually, I could resolve the `ModuleNotFoundError` by installing `lxml` and `requests` with `pip install`.
But now I get a `SyntaxError` when I try to import because somewhere `False = 0`....

Answer (score 3):

GMs answer only partly solved the problem for me (using Python 3.6 on Windows). Downloading [Twill 1.8.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twill) and converting it with `2to3` was only the first step.

Afterwards, I had to install missing packages:

```
pip install lxml
pip install requests
pip install pypiwin32
pip install cssselect
```

Furthermore, I had to fix two files in Python36/lib/site-packages/twill/other_packages/:
In `subprocess.py`, I removed the section with `False = 0` at line 392 and changed `if 0:` to `if 1:` in line 353 to avoid using `_subprocess`.
Finally, in `pyparsing.py`, I replaced `.lowercase` with `.lower()` and `.uppercase` with `.upper()`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Twill 2.0 is released with support of the modern python revisions

[Twill 2.0 Release Info Page](https://twill-tools.github.io/twill/changelog.html#released-2020-04-04)

Well, Twill 3 is also here -
[Twill 3](https://twill-tools.github.io/twill/changelog.html#released-2022-04-10)

Comment: Quick update: Current versions are now Twill 2.0.3 (Python 2 + 3) and Twill 3.0 (Python 3 only).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to install twill3?

```
pip install twill3
```