# Python reading url that requires logging in

Tags: python

I use

```
player_id = re.compile('<td><a href="(.+?)" onclick=')
url = 'http://www.csfbl.com/freeagents.asp?leagueid=2237'
sock = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode("utf-8")
```

or

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_html(url)
```

The website in question displays two different values based on whether I am logged in or not. How can I get the values as if I was logged in?

http://www.csfbl.com

is the website.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910221/how-can-i-login-to-a-website-with-python

Comment: i'm like... a newbie, i don't understand what i need to do... can you explain?

Comment: I logged in on chrome / explorer before running my code, it always returns the values as if I was not logged in... help?

Comment: I should have been more clear. If you want python to use the site as if you were logged in, then you would want to login using python.

Answer (score 2):

Use the *[requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)* module to submit the credentials on the web-form at: http://www.csfbl.com/logon.asp .

Instructions for submitting web forms using *requests* can be found here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Other sites can be more challenging.  For those, consider using [selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) or [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/).