# Python Script; Logging into site

Tags: python

I am trying to log into a site, 
https://www.telenor.no/privat/minesider/logginnfelles.cms?skin=telenor, with my user credentials. That site then redirects to https://www.telenor.no/privat/minesider/minside/minSide.cms.

I have tried all the different propsed solutions that I have found, but nothing has worked so far.. Is there someone out there that has a solution? Would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser, switch to the network tab; log in to the site. Look at the exchange happening. From that you could hopefully reverse-engineer the right sequence of HTTP requests you need to send.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your attempting to log into the website, but here's an article that shows how it's done in python. Maybe post your code on here so we can get an idea of what's going on.

[How can I login to a website with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910221/how-can-i-login-to-a-website-with-python)