# Login to Instagram and follow one account

Tags: python, instagram

I want to give 10 complimentary followers to the users who enter their Instagram username on my website.

I have pre-registered 10 Instagram profiles for this. ( E.g. IGprofile1, Igprofile2...Igprofile10).

When a user enters his username (E.g. kimkardashian) on the form and click submit, it'll be sent to my web server and give 10 followers to "kimkardashian"

IGprofile1-->login-->follow "kimkardashian" -->logout

IGprofile2-->login-->follow "kimkardashian" -->logout

....

....

IGprofile10-->login-->follow "kimkardashian" -->logout

I need this to on my server.

Below is a code one of my friend gave me

Any expert idea will be greatly appreciated.
.

```html
"""
    Follow
"""

import argparse
import sys
import os

from tqdm import tqdm

sys.path.append(os.path.join(sys.path[0], '../'))
from instabot import Bot

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=True)
parser.add_argument('user', type=str, help='user')
args = parser.parse_args()

# Add your bots here
BOTS_DATA = [
    {
        "username": "user1",
        "password": "pass1",
        "proxy": "https://127.0.0.1:3128"
    },
    {
        "username": "user2",
        "password": "pass2",
        "proxy": "https://127.0.0.1:3128"
    },
    {
        "username": "user3",
        "password": "pass3",
        "proxy": "https://127.0.0.1:3128"
    },
    {
        "username": "user4",
        "password": "pass4",
        "proxy": "https://127.0.0.1:3128"
    },
]

for bot in tqdm(BOTS_DATA):
    bot['bot'] = Bot()
    bot['bot'].login(username=bot['username'], password=bot['password'], proxy=bot['proxy'])
    bot['bot'].follow(args.user)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is a violation of Instagram's TOS.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to follow another user's account would be through using Instagram's API. Unfortunately, Instagram has recently stopped accepting applications for the `relationships` scope which permits such an action — refer to the Instagram documents [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/).

I cannot offer any advice on the matter, but you will also want to ensure you're building an application which aligns with Instagram's [Terms of Use](https://help.instagram.com/478745558852511) and [Platform Policy](https://www.instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/).

An alternative option to explore might be to look at automation with twill, for example — [How can I login to a website with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910221/how-can-i-login-to-a-website-with-python)