# Download image from website using chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome

I want to download some images (<10000) from a website.

I can't directly use the following python to directly download since the website requires username/password, it will give a 'HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized' error.

```
f = open(output_path, 'wb')
f.write(request.urlopen(full_image_url).read())
f.close()
```

So my current work around is to

1. log in to the website in Chrome - Easily Done
2. use python to parse (I manually copied the page source) and open lots of image links in chrome using 
   `webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(full_image_url)` - This is Done
3. save the image from browser to local hard drive.

For step 3, I can manually right click each chrome tab to 'save image as'. But is there an automatic way to do so?

Any suggestion, help link, or other work around solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to be logged in to see the image link?

Comment: Yes, I need to log in and then view the page source code in chrome. Then parse the code in python...

Comment: But once you have the page source with all the image urls in it, can you open the images without being logged in?

Comment: That is the problem. After logged in Chrome, I can directly open url link in chrome tab. But if I open link in python, it will give the unauthorized error. I guess the website can tell the difference between chrome client and python client.

Comment: I would look into selenium.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried logging into the site using python?
Take a look at this: [How can I login to a website with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910221/how-can-i-login-to-a-website-with-python)