# python login through web portal

Tags: python, web-scraping, automation, scrape, webautomation

Having issues using python to login to web portal. I've tried using suggestions from other posts

[How can I login to a website with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910221/how-can-i-login-to-a-website-with-python)

I've tried using twill (which failed to install because I'm running Python 3.6) - if anyone has suggestions how I can install it please advise

I've also tried using:

```
import requests
url = 'http://example.com/userinfo.php'
values = {'username': 'user',
          'password': 'pass'}

r = requests.post(url, data=values)
print(r.content)
```

with no luck.

The login page has the following html

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="/" style="padding-left:20px;" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="username">User Name:</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="User Name" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="ba_password2">Password:</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input id="ba_password2" type="password" placeholder="Password">
                            <input type="hidden" id="ba_username" name="ba_username">
                            <input type="hidden" name="ba_password">
                                                            <input type="hidden" name="ba_seed" value="614377365">
                            <input type="hidden" name="ba_salt" value="dgvwghgwuoyixgsrdhblkgigmtrhivbx">
                            <input type="hidden" name="ba_seedkey" value="-1647247092">
                                                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe"> Remember me on this computer
                            </label>
                            <button id="ba_loginbut" type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="msgHolder">
                                                    <div id="login-error-box" class="errormsg" style="display:none;">
                            <img src="/images/err.png"/>
                            <div id="login-error-msg"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="capslock" class="errormsg" style="display:none;">
                            <img src="/images/warn.png"/>
                            Caps lock is on.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

I hope someone can help. Thanks

Comment: it looks that it wants some extra variables beside the username / password, see the *hidden* input fields

Comment: I've also tried filling out all the hidden variables in the values. And no dice, is I'm not sure about the seeds though, as it re-generates everytime i re-fresh

Comment: probably cookies too

Comment: you need to be sure about how this data is sent. Check the page for possible jQuery stuf tied with handlers to the buttons. Try to figure out how it processes things when you hit the *Login button*

Comment: use Selenium and its method of sendkeys

Comment: Probably the site you want to login, uses the user and password just for some basic auth or an other auth method. If you provide us an url we could have a look through.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I know there is a login.js that is in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using libraries like `webbot` which even handle dynamically changing class and id for the webpage elements.

Answer (score 0):

With a Python code must looks like this:

```
#Open Firefox browser
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
#Enter email
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("email")
#Enter password
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("ba_password2")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pass")
#Click button
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("ba_loginbut")
elem.click()
```