# [Python]Is there a way to simulate login to a site using gmail account?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting, google-authentication

I am trying to login to a site where I quick-registered using my Gmail account, so every time I login, I have to login through Gmail, and I don't have any specific username/password.

I want my Python script to login to the site using my Gmail credentials, fetch a few PDFs from it, and log-out.

I am stuck at the logging-in part. I tried to inspect the ["Sign in with Google"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgEU9.png) page, to find a url to post my credentials to (as per the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28628514/12802139)), but all I see is some *jsaction* and *jscontrollers* tags which I can't comprehend.

Any sort of help will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: You can use Selenium to do this. Check out [this tutorial](https://crossbrowsertesting.com/blog/test-automation/automate-login-with-selenium/) on how to use Selenium to login to websites. Once you understand the tutorial, you will have to find the ids for your Google login page so that you can insert the text in the correct place. Good luck on your project! :)