# search for login pages on a website using python

Tags: python, automation

Is there any way if we can automate to find the login pages available on different website using python ? I haven't started working on the code but looking for ideas.

Comment: Does this help? [How can I login to a website with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910221/how-can-i-login-to-a-website-with-python)

Comment: no, this wouldn't look for login pages available in a domain. so what I am trying to do If I have a list of domains (e.g. abc.com, xyz.com etc) and I have to search for login url (if available) on on each domain and print the result  how can I do that

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.